# Proving a generalized Bernoulli's inequality (for real exponents)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I have already proved that for any real $a>0$, we have $(1+a)^r>1+ra$ for any $r\in \mathbb{Q}>1.$

I want to use this fact in order to prove that the same inequality holds even when $r\in \mathbb{R}>1.$ I came up with the following: Let $(r_n)$ be a sequence of rationals that converge to $r$ and satisfies $r_n>1$ for each $n$. This means that,
$$(1+a)^{r_n}>1+r_na, \quad \text{for all }n.$$
Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ gives $(1+a)^{r}\geq 1+ra$, so now I just need to prove that $(1+a)^r=1+ra$ is not possible when $a>0$ and $r>1$, I've tried but nothing seems to work, I think proving this should be possible with some calculus, but I would prefer an elementary proof.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Pick rational $q$ with $1<q<r$. Then, using monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^s$ when $s>1$ and $x>0$,
$$(1+a)^r=\left((1+a)^q\right)^{r/q} > (1+qa)^{r/q}\ge 1+\frac rqqa=1+ra$$

Comment: Just an explanation of this answer, the second "$\geq$" comes from the limiting process of Bernoulli's inequality of rational numbers.

Comment: How did you get the last step of the inequality?

Comment: Okay, so after struggling for almost a day, the last step of the inequality comes from applying the proven result with qa > 0 and r/q > 1.